# Trouble understanding an amplifier and filter circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter

[image]

First time poster and a beginner at electronics, please tell me if any formatting is wrong.

I implemented this amplifier and filter circuit and connected it with a function generator as input to see if it worked. It did, but I do not understand it's behaviour. At about 70k frequency, input 272mV gives me 1.56V as output. But the gain starts to be less than 1 when I put anything above 1V as input. For example, 4.8V gives me 280mV as output. All this was observed on an oscilloscope. Would anyone please  explain how that happens?

Comment: Try to workout the transfer function of your circuit, that will help you to understand the frequency response and the bandwidth of your circuit

Comment: Where did you connect the input? Please show details.

Comment: Voltage outputs of LM324 cannot be near its negative power supply if the amplifier is to operate normally, and the output 2N3904 requires an emitter pulldown to operate normally as a buffer amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

Your 68k resistors are tied to ground, which is the negative supply of the op-amps. I suggest adding a 68k to 5V for each one. This will prevent the op-amps from saturating.

Comment: I don't think that will be enough. There's no DC negative feedback path on the first op-amp. It's going to saturate.